# Display define-key output in echo area

Tags: key-bindings, echo-area, keystrokes

This is my function,

```
(define-key global-map
  (kbd "µ")
  (display-message-or-buffer (message "`%s'" (eval '(solar-sunrise-sunset-string (calendar-current-date))))))
```

But, when I call it, through the `alt+m` keystroke the command literally outputs text where my cursor is, with the output.

For example, under my cursor, the text appears as so,
[image]

How can I direct this message to my `Echo Area`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is defining the key to the *result of the evaluation of the expression* `` (display-message-or-buffer (message "`%s'" (eval '(solar-sunrise-sunset-string (calendar-current-date))))) ``. When I evaluate that expression in my `*scratch*` buffer, I get the string `"‘Sunrise 7:04am (EST), sunset 4:10pm (EST) at 42.4N, 71.2W (9:06 hrs daylight)’"`. IOW, what you did is equivalent to this:

```el
(define-key global-map (kbd "µ") "‘Sunrise 7:04am (EST), sunset 4:10pm (EST) at 42.4N, 71.2W (9:06 hrs daylight)’")
```

Of course, geographical differences will give you a different string, but that is irrelevant to the main point.

If you want to define the key to run a command, you first define the function that you want to run and then you give the *function* to `define-key` - like this:

```el
(defun my/func ()
  (interactive)
  (display-message-or-buffer (message "`%s'" (eval '(solar-sunrise-sunset-string (calendar-current-date)))))

(define-key global-map (kbd "µ") #'my/func)
```

BTW, you don't need the `eval`:  `` (display-message-or-buffer (message "`%s'" (solar-sunrise-sunset-string (calendar-current-date)))) `` will work just as well (or better: explicit use of `eval` is generally frowned upon - see the first paragraph of the `eval` section of the Emacs Lisp manual, which you can get to with `C-h v i g(elisp)eval`).